# Count records which appeared in each previous years

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table which has columns `id` and `year`. I want to find out the number of ids which appeared in every previous years.

> Sample Table

```
id | year | 
---+------+
 1 | 2017 |
 2 | 2017 | 
 1 | 2018 | 
 2 | 2018 |
 3 | 2018 |
 4 | 2019 |
 3 | 2019 |
 1 | 2019 |
```

> Expected Output

```
 | 2017 | 2 |
 | 2018 | 2 |
 | 2019 | 1 |
```

In 2017, 1 and 2 appeared so count is 2. In 2018, 1 2 and 3 appeared but only 1 and 2 appeared in 2017 so count for 2018 is 2. In 2019, 1 3 and 4 appeared, but only 1 appeared in 2017 and 2018 so the count for 2019 is 1.

Comment: . . I happen to think this is a good question.  I have no idea why it was downvoted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - "The question does not show any research effort"

Comment: @DaleBurrell . . . Odd that you say that.  The specific problem doesn't ring a bell to me.  Two people attempted to answer incorrectly.  This is not obvious to most people; although perhaps it is to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the ids and the year and compare them:

```
select year, count(*)
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over (partition by id order by year) as seqnum_id,
        dense_rank() over (order by year) as seqnum_year
    from t
) t
where seqnum_id = seqnum_year
group by year;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=24fe9bdc0636524eb9a31841aba9931a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Now another thing comes into my mind. if there is duplicate entry for a year (say 1 appears twice in 2018) will this work?
p.s I have checked with duplicate entry in the fiddle you provided. Not working.

Comment: @AdnanNiloy . . . No.  You can use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()` for `seqnum_id`.